# Mystery undesired split-by-period in python re.split()

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string `cleanFunc` e.g.

`cleanFunc = "3.04x^2.48"`

When I use

`terms = re.split("[+-/*^()]+",cleanFunc)`

The result for `terms` is

`terms: ['3', '04x', '2', '48']`

I don't have a period `.` anywhere in the regex and for some reason the function is splitting when it scans a period. How can I avoid this? Any flags I can add to explicitly avoid splitting by periods? I've already tried to avoid removing periods by the following regex:

```
terms = re.split("(?<!\d)[.](?!\d)|[+-/*^()]+",cleanFunc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is your '-' sign in there, which denotes 'from a - b' in ASCII characters, which would include periods, presumably.

Change your regex to escape it, like this:

```
terms = re.split(r"[+\-/*^()]+", cleanFunc)
```

and it works how you want it to.

Comment: I wonder if `-` is the only character within brackets that maintains its functionality (that needs to be escaped)...?

Comment: I believe it is, according to my work with regexes and the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, everything else is treated as a character.